# OSError ssl handshake?

Tags: python, firebase-realtime-database, error-handling, runtime-error

I'm new to python and I have trouble analysing the following errors. Does someone know why my script crashed?

I'm scraping the web for some data and everytime the scraper hits, the script writes that time into database (to check if the script is still alive). Every couple of days the script crashes.

Thanks in advance.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 849, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 356, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 359, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 850, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1108, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
OSError: [Errno 0] Error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 445, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 367, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 849, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 356, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 359, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 850, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1108, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/firebase_admin/db.py", line 881, in request
    return super(_Client, self).request(method, url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/firebase_admin/_http_client.py", line 84, in request
    resp = self._session.request(method, self._base_url + url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 201, in request
    method, url, data=data, headers=request_headers, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 512, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 622, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 495, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 32, in <module>
    firebase.write_time_stamp(for_js)
  File "/firebase.py", line 38, in write_time_stamp
    'time': stamp
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/firebase_admin/db.py", line 339, in update
    self._client.request('patch', self._add_suffix(), json=value, params='print=silent')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/firebase_admin/db.py", line 883, in request
    raise ApiCallError(_Client.extract_error_message(error), error)
firebase_admin.db.ApiCallError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error'))
```